# InnoDB FOR UPDATE Transaction causes php fatal error, Maximum Execution time

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, innodb, cakephp-1.2

The situation is something like the following:
1- MySQL InnoDB table undergo to transactional select as follows:

```
     <?php

        ....
        doQuery('START TRANSACTION');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table where amount < 10 FOR UPDATE";
       $res = $doQuery($sql);
// Then a looping through $res includes updates to some fields -amount field- in the same table and set it to values greater than 10

//After the loop
doQuery('COMMIT');
```

At the XAMPP localhost, I opened two different browsers' windows, FireFox and Opera, requesting The script URL at the same time. I expect that only one of them could able to retrieve values for $res. However, The script returns Fetal Error

> Blockquote
>   Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

I need to know the cause of this Error? Does it due to the two clients, FireFox and Opera, don't able to select or because they are not able to update?
Also I need a solution that keep transaction and give me the expected result, i.e. only one browser can return results!

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with browsers. How many rows are in the table? And what does your update statement look like?

Comment: The table rows do not exceed 30 row at this time, it is very small!
About the update statement, it executed inside the loop and update records in the $res.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just add `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of the script but it's not a good solution for scripts accessible via http.

Comment: I don't think that is the solution because the problem is not in execution time itself, it is related with locks generated in the transaction. The total records in the database till this moment does not exceed 30 record. In other word, in most long loop, it may be looping from 3 to 5 times as maximum.

Comment: Oh because your answer is the only one answer and during my examinations It solved some issues and clarifying some concepts, I found it the nearest one to the correct. However, it need to set time limit greater that the innodb_lock_wait_timeout which it by default is 50 seconds. However, the dynamic set -during run time- for innodb_lock_wait_timeout is not available in MySQL before 5.6 most hosting runs 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Your script enters a `dead lock`. To avoid this, add an `ORDER BY` to the query, to ensure that both queries will try to select the records in the same order. Also make sure there is index on `amount`, otherwise the query will have to lock the entire table.